# jquery $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); doesnt seem to be working in IE8?

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8

I am using `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });` but it doesn't seem to be working in IE8? I am making a number of get/post Ajax calls on a page. If I leave the page and come back, it seems as if my Ajax calls are still cached even though I've set this to false. I know this because I don't see certain updated information that is present in the database, but doesn't come through in the Ajax call. If I close the whole IE window and then go back to the page, then I see the updated information?

At this point I think I might just explicitly add a random number to the request(s), although isn't that what cache: false is supposed to do anyway?

Comment: When you "leave the page and come back," are you using the Back button? Depending on the HTTP headers that your pages are served with, the entire page might be retrieved from the cache when using the Back button.

Comment: No I am leaving the page by clicking another link.

Comment: But are you returning to the page using the Back button?

Comment: Yes. Do you think I need "no-cache" headers on the page, at least for IE?

Comment: Yes, I think that might be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/ it's use isn't recommended. Try using $.ajax({cache: false}) instead.